# Анимация градиента с перекрыванием одного цвета другим

Tags: javascript, css3, svg, анимация, svg-animation

В качестве основного фонового изображения используется следующий линейный градиент:

```css
html, body, svg {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="gradient">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="brown"/>
<stop offset="2" stop-color="chocolate"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100vh" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
```

Как мы знаем, градиент — это плавный переход от одного цвета к другому. Самих цветов и переходов между ними может быть несколько. В данном примере используется только два цвета — коричневый и шоколадный.

Мне необходимо реализовать анимацию этого градиента. Нужно пустить разделяющую вертикальную белую полосу, которая будет двигаться слева направо, и затем в обратном направлении. Таким образом, удаляясь от одного края, эта полоса будет как-бы тянуть градиент за собой, тем самым заполняя основной фон плавным переходом от одного цвета к белому. Затем в обратном направлении, заполняя основной фон плавным переходом от другого цвета к белому.

[image: Градиент]

Сценарий анимации:

1. Вертикальная белая полоса двигается слева направо, заполняя основной фон плавным переходом от коричневого к белому;
2. Вертикальная белая полоса двигается справа налево, заполняя основной фон плавным переходом от шоколадного к белому;
3. Анимация зацикливается.

Это самый простой сценарий такой анимации. Однако, если это возможно, то мне хотелось бы этот сценарий немного усложнить:

1. Вертикальная белая полоса двигается слева направо, заполняя основной фон плавным переходом от коричневого к белому. За время этой анимации основное фоновое изображение трансформируется в виде вращения на 360<sup>o</sup> по часовой стрелке;
2. Вертикальная белая полоса двигается справа налево, заполняя основной фон плавным переходом от шоколадного к белому. За время этой анимации основное фоновое изображение трансформируется в виде вращения на 360<sup>o</sup> против часовой стрелки;
3. Анимация зацикливается.

Реализовать такую анимацию предлагается любыми средствами, указанными в метках вопроса, а именно — как `CSS`, `SMIL SVG`, так и с помощью `JavaScript` (*а это может быть и Canvas - HTML элемент, использующий язык программирования - JavaScript*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во всех примерах ниже `gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"` это дефолтное значение, поэтому, если не указано явно `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` значения атрибутов будут либо в процентах, либо соответственно `от 0 до 1`  Что означает, что градиент будет действовать на всю фигуру.

Анимировать будем значения атрибутов градиента `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`

*#1. Перемещение белой полосы с протяжкой цвета слева-направо*

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0">
         <animate attributeName="x2" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1"  dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
         <stop offset="0%" stop-color="brown"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="chocolate"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="240" height="240" rx="25" fill="url(#Gradient)"/>
  
</svg>
```

*#2. Вращение белой полосы*

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <animate attributeName="x1" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y1" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="x2" values="1;1;0;0;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y2" values="1;0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="brown"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="chocolate"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="240" height="240" rx="25" fill="url(#Gradient)"/>
  
</svg>
```

*#3. Вращение белой полосы с другими цветами внутри звезды*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="475.07" height="475.07" viewBox="0 0 475.075 475.075" fill="#FFF">
<defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <animate attributeName="x1" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y1" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="x2" values="1;1;0;0;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y2" values="1;0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
<path fill="url(#Gradient)"  d="M324.63 288.5l20.55 120.2-107.63-56.82L129.6 408.7l20.86-120.2-87.37-84.8L183.57 186l53.95-109.06L291.5 186 412 203.7l-87.38 84.8z"/>
</svg>
```

**#4. Двойная звезда вращение градиента на нижнем контуре**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="475.07" height="475.07" viewBox="0 0 475.075 475.075" fill="#FFF">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <animate attributeName="x1" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y1" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="x2" values="1;1;0;0;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y2" values="1;0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="brown"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="chocolate"/>
      </linearGradient>
</defs>   
<path  fill="url(#Lg)" stroke="brown"   stroke-width="1" d="M475.07 186.57c0-7.04-5.32-11.42-16-13.13l-143.3-20.84-64.24-129.9c-3.62-7.8-8.28-11.7-14-11.7-5.7 0-10.36 3.9-13.98 11.7L159.3 152.6 16 173.44c-10.67 1.7-16 6.1-16 13.13 0 4 2.38 8.57 7.14 13.7l103.92 101.08L86.5 444.1c-.37 2.66-.56 4.57-.56 5.7 0 4 1 7.38 3 10.14 2 2.77 5 4.15 9 4.15 3.42 0 7.22-1.15 11.4-3.44l128.2-67.38 128.2 67.38c4 2.28 7.8 3.43 11.4 3.43 7.82 0 11.72-4.76 11.72-14.28 0-2.48-.1-4.38-.3-5.72l-24.54-142.74L467.66 200.3c4.94-4.97 7.4-9.54 7.4-13.73z"/>
    
    <path fill="brown" stroke="shocolate" stroke-width="2" d="M324.63 288.5l20.55 120.2-107.63-56.82L129.6 408.7l20.86-120.2-87.37-84.8L183.57 186l53.95-109.06L291.5 186 412 203.7l-87.38 84.8z"/>
</svg>
```

*#5. Двойная звезда разные, вращающиеся градиенты на разные контуры*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="475.07" height="475.07" viewBox="0 0 475.075 475.075" fill="#FFF">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="Lg1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <animate attributeName="x1" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y1" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="x2" values="1;1;0;0;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y2" values="1;0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="brown"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="chocolate"/>
      </linearGradient> 
     <linearGradient id="Lg2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <animate attributeName="x1" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y1" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="x2" values="1;1;0;0;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y2" values="1;0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="brown"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="crimson"/>
      </linearGradient> 
</defs>   
<path  fill="url(#Lg1)" stroke="black"  stroke-width="1" d="M475.07 186.57c0-7.04-5.32-11.42-16-13.13l-143.3-20.84-64.24-129.9c-3.62-7.8-8.28-11.7-14-11.7-5.7 0-10.36 3.9-13.98 11.7L159.3 152.6 16 173.44c-10.67 1.7-16 6.1-16 13.13 0 4 2.38 8.57 7.14 13.7l103.92 101.08L86.5 444.1c-.37 2.66-.56 4.57-.56 5.7 0 4 1 7.38 3 10.14 2 2.77 5 4.15 9 4.15 3.42 0 7.22-1.15 11.4-3.44l128.2-67.38 128.2 67.38c4 2.28 7.8 3.43 11.4 3.43 7.82 0 11.72-4.76 11.72-14.28 0-2.48-.1-4.38-.3-5.72l-24.54-142.74L467.66 200.3c4.94-4.97 7.4-9.54 7.4-13.73z"/>
    
    <path fill="url(#Lg2)" stroke="black" d="M324.63 288.5l20.55 120.2-107.63-56.82L129.6 408.7l20.86-120.2-87.37-84.8L183.57 186l53.95-109.06L291.5 186 412 203.7l-87.38 84.8z"/>
</svg>
```

### Другие примеры с протяжкой цвета за бегущей полосой

*#1. Горизонтально слева-направо и обратно*

```html
<style>
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#Lg');
}
</style>
<svg class="the-svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-20 -20 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FF00AE"/>
    <animate attributeName="x1" dur="4s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

#2. Вертикальная протяжка цвета

```html
<style>
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#Lg');
}
</style>
<svg class="the-svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-20 -20 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FF00AE"/>
    <animate attributeName="y1" dur="4s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

*#3. Под углом*

```html
<style>
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#Lg');
}
</style>
<svg class="the-svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-10 -10 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FF00AE"/>
      <animate attributeName="x1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      <animate attributeName="y1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

*#4.Смена пары цветов на другую пару при наведении курсора*
(по моему выглядит симпатично)

```html
<style>
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#Lg');
}
 .crc1 ~ defs stop {
  transition: 3s;
}

.crc1 ~ defs stop:first-child {
  stop-color: #24bed2;
}
.crc1:hover ~ defs stop:last-child {
  stop-color: #F4FFAF;
} 
</style>
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-10 -10 120 120">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  stroke="#F4FFAF"/>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="90" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="2%" stop-color="#2C2C2C"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#2C2C2C"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

[BONUS]

*Вращение трех колец с градиентной анимацией*

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

svg {
background:black;
}

#path1 {
fill:url(#gradl);
stroke:none;
fill-opacity:1;
}
#path2 {
fill:url(#grad2);
stroke:none;
fill-opacity:0.8;
}
#crc1 {
stroke:none;
fill:black;
}
#txt1 {
fill:url(#grad2);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 300 300" > 
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradl" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"> 
             <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.5s" values="dodgerblue;yellow;dodgerblue" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" />   
             </stop>             
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow">
           <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.5s" values="yellow;dodgerblue;yellow" repeatCount="indefinite"  restart="whenNotActive" />    
             </stop>                        
            
        </linearGradient> 
        <linearGradient id="grad2" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="lime">
              <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.5s" values="lime;purple;lime" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" />  
             </stop>                
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="purple">
           <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.5s" values="purple;lime;purple" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive"  />  
             </stop>                
        </linearGradient>
    
        </defs>
<path id="path1" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" > 
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 150 150;360 150 150" begin="svg1.click" dur="20s" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
</path>

<path id="path2" transform="rotate(45 150 150)" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" >
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="360 148 148;0 148 148" begin="svg1.click" dur="20s" restart="whenNotActive" />  
</path>
<circle id="crc1" cx="150" cy="150" r="90" /> 
 <text id="txt1" x="80" y="160" font-size="36" font-weight="700" > Click me </text>
</svg>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
CSS.registerProperty && CSS.registerProperty({
  name: '--linepos',
  syntax: '<length-percentage>',
  inherits: true,
  initialValue: 0,
});
```

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  --linepos: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, chocolate, white 50%, brown);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, chocolate, white var(--linepos), brown);
  animation: linepos 3s alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes linepos {
  from { --linepos: 0% }
  to { --linepos: 100% }
}

@property --linepos {
  syntax: '<length-percentage>';
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

С поворотом как-то так, но пока не получилось:

```js
CSS.registerProperty && CSS.registerProperty({
  name: '--linepos',
  syntax: '<length-percentage>',
  inherits: true,
  initialValue: 0,
});

CSS.registerProperty && CSS.registerProperty({
  name: '--slope',
  syntax: '<angle>',
  inherits: true,
  initialValue: "0turn",
});
```

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  --linepos: 50%;
  --slope: .25turn;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, chocolate, white 50%, brown);
  background: linear-gradient(var(--slope), chocolate, white var(--linepos), brown);
  animation: anim 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from   { --linepos:   0%;   --slope:  .25turn; }
  50%    { --linepos: 100%;   --slope:  .75turn; }
  to     { --linepos:   0%;   --slope: 1.25turn; }
}

@property --linepos {
  syntax: '<length-percentage>';
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0;
}

@property --slope {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0turn;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol', я бы сказал, что у нас совершенно разные решения) Я тут попробовал поворот приделать - чую, что надо подумать над математикой, но пока фигня. И у анимации переменных поддержка пока так себе.

Comment: @Sevastopol', ну тут косяк в том, что когда переворачивается точка отсчёта, сдвиг начинает считаться справа, а не слева, а значит в правую половину центр белой полосы никогда не попадает. Но ещё мне кажется, что с отсчётом процентов при наклоне тоже что-то было не то, хотя не уверен. Кажется, надо где-то что-то прибавить в анимации, но я пока не понял, что и где. Хотя да, смотрится интересно.

Comment: @Sevastopol', `@keyframes anim { 0% { --linepos: 0%; --slope: .25turn; } 25% { --linepos: 50%; --slope: .50turn; } 50% { --linepos: 0%; --slope: .75turn; } 75% { --linepos: 50%; --slope: 1.00turn; } 100% { --linepos: 0%; --slope: 1.25turn; } }` - так правдоподобнее, но задержка на горизонтальном положении явно не в тему.

Comment: @Sevastopol', ой, ёёёёё.. Я даже не заметил, что у меня его нет. Да, гораздо лучше, только всё равно визуально видно моментальную смену точки вращения.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант анимации по первому (упрощённому) сценарию с помощью технологии `SMIL SVG`.

Чтобы реализовать такую анимацию, нам необходимо добавить еще один цвет для градиента — белый:

```
<stop stop-color="white">
```

Добавляем анимацию, и указываем для нее необходимые атрибуты и значения:

`attributeName=offset` — этот параметр отвечает за границу области градиента;

`dur=5s` — длительность анимации;

`values=0;1;0` — список значений, который будет определять порядок следования анимации;

`repeatCount=indefinite` — количество раз выполнения анимации. Значение `indefinite` указывает на то, что анимация будет повторяться бесконечно.

Всё это заключаем в тег `<animate>`:

```
<animate attributeName="offset" dur="5s" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```css
html, body, svg {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="gradient">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="brown"/>
<stop stop-color="white">
<animate attributeName="offset" dur="5s" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" /></stop>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="chocolate"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100vh" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
```

Повернем угол наклона градиентной линии на 90<sup>o</sup>

```css
html, body, svg {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90 0 0)">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="brown"/>
<stop stop-color="white">
<animate attributeName="offset" dur="5s" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" /></stop>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="chocolate"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100vh" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

### CSS решение

Белая полоса и её анимация появляются при наведении курсора

- Белая полоса формируется с помощью `linear-gradient`

```
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom,brown, #fff 30px, chocolate 60px)
   no-repeat 0 -100px /100% 10%, chocolate;
```

- Анимация движения белой полосы реализовано с помощью изменения
  `background-position`

*Горизонтальная анимация*

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.box{
  width:100vw;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:chocolate;
  min-height:25vh;
 
}
.box:hover{
  background:linear-gradient(to right,brown, #fff 30px, chocolate 60px) no-repeat -100px 0/100px 100%, chocolate;
 animation:draw 3s ease-in-out alternate infinite; 
}
@keyframes draw{
  from{
    background-position:-35px 0;
  }
  to{
    background-position:105% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

*Вертикальная анимация*

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.box{
  width:15vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:chocolate;
  min-height:50vh;
  transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover{
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,brown, #fff 30px, chocolate 60px) no-repeat 0 -100px /100% 10%, chocolate;
  animation:draw 4s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes draw{
  from{
    background-position:5% 0%;
  }
  to{
    background-position: 5% 105%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант анимации по первому (упрощённому) сценарию с помощью технологии `CSS`

Такую анимацию в данном варианте мы можем реализовать с помощью псевдоэлементов `::before` и `::after` к элементу `<body>`, а также правил `@keyframes`, установив общие ключевые кадры, включая в них свойства ширины `width` (для первого варианта) или высоты `height` (для второго варианта).

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100vh; position: relative;}

body::before, body::after {
  content: ""; display: block; height: 100vh; width: 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
}

body::before {
  left: 0; background: linear-gradient(90deg, brown, white);
  animation: before 5s linear infinite;
}

body::after {
  right: 0; background: linear-gradient(90deg, white, chocolate);
  animation: after 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes before {
  0% {width: 0;}
  50% {width: 100%;}
  100% {width: 0;}
}

@keyframes after {
  0% {width: 100%;}
  50% {width: 0;}
  100% {width: 100%;}
}
```

Повернем угол наклона градиентной линии на 90<sup>o</sup>

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100vh; position: relative;}

body::before, body::after {
  content: ""; display: block; height: 100vh; width: 100%;
  position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;
}

body::before {
  top: 0; background: linear-gradient(180deg, brown, white);
  animation: before 5s linear infinite;
}

body::after {
  bottom: 0; background: linear-gradient(180deg, white, chocolate);
  animation: after 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes before {
  0% {height: 0;}
  50% {height: 100%;}
  100% {height: 0;}
}

@keyframes after {
  0% {height: 100%;}
  50% {height: 0;}
  100% {height: 100%;}
}
```