# Как сделать вращение градиента с белой полосой с помощью CSS по краю элемента

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Получилось выполнить вращение градиента средствами SVG с помощью анимации атрибутов `x1`, `x2`, `y1` `y2`

```
<animate attributeName="x1" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    <animate attributeName="y1" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

Но не получилось сделать это с помощью анимации градиентов CSS.

Вот мой ***SVG код*** анимации вращения градиентов с белой полосой:

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg1" version="1.1" width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 210 210" border="1">

  
 <defs>
<linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <animate attributeName="x1" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y1" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="x2" values="1;1;0;0;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y2" values="1;0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00C256"/>
      </linearGradient>
</defs>   
 
  <path fill="url(#Lg)" stroke="none"  id="hex_Out" d="m105 5 86.6 50 0 100L105 205 18.4 155l0-100zM105 20l73.6 42.5 0 85" />
  <path  fill="#00C256" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" id="hex_Ind" d="m105 20 73.6 42.5 0 85L105 190 31.4 147.5l0-85z" />
  </svg>
  </div>
```

**Вопрос:**

Как сделать вращение градиента с белой полосой с помощью CSS по краю элемента?

Answer (score 4):

Прежде чем ответить на этот вопрос, для начала нужно нарисовать такую фигуру, какая обозначена в вопросе - шестиугольник. Это мы можем сделать, например, с помощью свойства `clip-path`.

Градиент создаем с помощью универсального свойства `background` и функции `linear-gradient()`.

Анимацию будем выполнять с помощью правила `@keyframes`, установив для него общие ключевые кадры, включая в них свойство `background`. Так как у нас градиент линейный и указан угол наклона градиентной линии, то ключевыми кадрами мы и будем его менять. Пример ниже:

```css
div {
  position: relative; width: 180px; height: 200px; background: #00C256; clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #24bed2, white, #00C256);
  animation: ani 1s linear infinite;
}

div::before {content: ""; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 140px; height: 160px; background: white; clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);}
div::after {content: ""; position: absolute; top: 22px; left: 22px; width: 136px; height: 156px; background: #00C256; clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);}

@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #24bed2, white, #00C256);
  }
  25% {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #24bed2, white, #00C256);
  }
  50% {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #24bed2, white, #00C256);
  }
  75% {
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #24bed2, white, #00C256);
  }
  100% {
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, #24bed2, white, #00C256);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Однако, такая анимация воспроизводит немного другой эффект в отличие от того, который продемонстрирован в вопросе. В таком случае нам нужна другая реализация. И, для того, чтобы добиться плавности такой анимации, учитывая ее работоспособность не только в Chromium браузерах, желательно не угол наклона градиентной линии менять, а использовать свойство `transform` и функцию `rotate`. Для этого создадим дополнительный элемент, к которому и применим такую анимацию. Пример:

```css
div {
position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 180px; height: 200px;
clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
}

div::before {content: ""; z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 140px; height: 160px; background: white; clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);}
div::after {content: ""; z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 22px; left: 22px; width: 136px; height: 156px; background: #00C256; clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);}

div>span {
  display: block; position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; width: 200px; height: 220px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #24bed2, white, #00C256);
  animation: ani 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);;
  }
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```

Таким образом мы можем применить подобную анимацию к любой фигуре. Например, как в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1267755/377637) участника @Alexandr_TT к вопросу "[Анимация градиента с перекрыванием одного цвета другим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1266866/377637)". Варианты с двойной звездой особенно заслуживают отдельного внимания.

Comment: Замечательно получилось! Проверил во всех современных браузерах, включая `FF` и даже `Edge` Подожду немного, так как зелёная галочка почему-то отбивает у людей давать свои ответы, но не забуду, кто первый дал кроссбраузерный, правильный ответ. Пока в другом месте (+)

Answer (score 4):

Чуть изменил ответ [`@Sevastopol'`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/377637/sevastopol) и всё заработало.

Работает только в Chromium браузерах

```css
@property --deg {
  syntax: "<angle>";
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #00C256;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  background: linear-gradient(var(--deg, 0deg), #24bed2, white, #00C256);
  animation: ani 1s linear infinite;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 160px;
  background: white;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 22px;
  width: 136px;
  height: 156px;
  background: #00C256;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
}

@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    --deg: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    --deg: 360deg;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать кроссбраузерный вариант решения. И вы хотели изучать SVG, попробуйте сделать и  вариант SVG. Я разместил этот вопрос именно в учебных целях и буду ждать ответа сколько понадобится времени

Comment: @Sevastopol' чем больше я буду применять эту технологию, тем быстрее она появится :D

Comment: @Sevastopol' надо дождаться, когда Houdini начнёт поддерживаться в Mozilla https://ishoudinireadyyet.com/ , тогда заработает, возможно. Сейчас там на рассмотрении многие приколюхи

Comment: У меня в лисе не работает.)

Comment: @Sevastopol' я иногда дебажу чужой код ... есть для этого средства

Comment: @Sevastopol' я об этом культурно обычно говорю ..если не понимают или подозревают то что я придумал - снимаю видео